# ¿Por qué a las listas horizontales hay que ponerles overflow: hidden?

Tags: css

Tengo una duda con la propiedad `overflow` a la hora de hacer listas horizontales. He visto un ejemplo en W3Schools, donde se utiliza esta propiedad para la etiqueta `ul`, y no termino de entender cuál es su funcionamiento, ni siquiera por qué es necesaria.
Entiendo que la propiedad `overflow` ni siquiera debería ser necesaria, y tampoco entiendo por qué al cambiar su valor desaparece completamente la lista.

Creo que no existe en el ejemplo ningún desborde de contenido, por lo que la propiedad `overflow` no debería tener ningún sentido en este ejemplo.

Os dejo el enlace a ver si alguien me puede echar una mano. Muchas gracias.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_menu

Answer (score 3):

Eso se debe a que los elementos `li` están definidos con la propiedad `float: left` y el `ul` no tiene una altura definida.

El `overflow: hidden` lo que permite es, que si un elemento que no tiene altura y alguno de sus elementos internos contienen la propiedad `float: left`, el elemento padre obtiene la altura de sus elementos hijos. En cambio, si lo quitas, el "cortado" que hace la propiedad `overflow` no se realiza y, por tanto, al no tener una altura definida el `ul`, este no se muestra (si te fijas los `li` si que están -flotando- en la pantalla pero como tienen el texto en blanco no se ven hasta que pasas por encima de ellos).

**Nota:** Este comportamiento no se da únicamente con el valor `hidden`, si no con cualquier valor para `overflow` que no sea el de por defecto y que haga una función de "recorte", como por ejemplo, `auto` o `scroll`.

Comment: Gracias Francisco, creo que he entendido lo que me dices en relación al ```overflow```, el ```float```, el ```ul``` y la falta de altura, pero después de hacer algunas pruebas y de comprobar (no me había dado cuenta antes) lo que me dices de el ```background-color``` no definido en el ```li```, sino en el ```ul```, creo que discrepo en parte de tu explicación (seguramente nuevamente por mi desconocimiento).

Verás, he editado el CSS, y he visto que simplemente poniendo el ```background-color``` en el ```li``` se consigue ver el elemento, independiente de que comentes, o no, el ```overflow```

Comment: @HugoSanchez El `background-color` se pone en el `ul` porque de esta manera la barra de navegación llega hasta el final. Si te fijas (puedes hacer la prueba), cambiando el `background-color` a los `li` el negro solo ocupa el espacio que ocupan los `li` pero no el total del espacio hasta el final de la linea.

Comment: Efectivamente. Muchas gracias por tus repuestas.

Creo que voy a darle un buen repaso a las etiquetas porque se me van muchas cosas.

Muchas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: @HugoSanchez Es un placer :). La verdad es que CSS tiene algunas cosas que la primera vez que las ves se escapan del raciocinio humano xDD